# Import shapefile as table in MS SQL Server (QGIS 3)?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have made a successful connection with MS SQL Server in QGIS 3.  I can see all of the tables. I know with QGIS 2 and PostgreSQL you had to use DB Manager to import a shapefile as a table.  Well, DB Manager doesn't have the option for MSSQL... Is there an alternative plugin?

Comment: To load requires a bit more work - I will post a python script I use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the in-built browser panel. Just drag and drop a layer (either from your project, or from somewhere else in the browser) onto a schema in the mssql connection to copy the data across.

Comment: Thank you Nyall!
I've spent the last 2 days refining my fme/python/ogr2ogr function when I could have done this. Any which way the fme/python/ogr2ogr logic is still required to resolve my automations

Answer (score 1):

I've shared this before on this forum, but please have a look at the following and let me know if it works for you. It should only use

```
import os

#Define input SHP and database parameters:
#location of OSGEO4W:
osgeo4w = 'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\OSGeo4W.bat'
servername = 'servername'
databasename = 'databasename'
sourceshp = 'shp\shapefile_name.shp'
crs_source = '4326'
crs_dest = '4326'
#Define MSSQL Destination Table Name
desttable = 'plangis.temp_pyogr2ogr_trusted'

### Script runs with the above parameters:
##########
#build OGR2OGR statement

#as trusted connection
cmd = 'call "' + osgeo4w + '" ' \
      'ogr2ogr -skipfailures -overwrite -progress -nln ' \
       + desttable + ' -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:driver={SQL Server};server=' \
      + servername +';database=' + databasename + ';trusted_connection=yes" ' \
      + sourceshp + ' -s_srs EPSG:' + crs_source + ' -t_srs EPSG:' + crs_dest + \
      ' -lco geom_name=shape -lco UPLOAD_GEOM_FORMAT=wkt -lco FID=objectid'

##########


#test OGR2OGR statement
print cmd

print "Loading PGSQL table to MSSQL"

#run command
os.system(cmd)

print "Table Loaded"
```

Basically I have this script sitting in a folder, and whatever SHP I want to load, I put it in a SHP folder at the same level I have the python script (see the SHP/shapefile_name.shp above).

I run the script and its good to go!

Let me know what you think!

Comment: Thankyou.  I have tried a few things with OGR2OGR and ran into a few problems so far.  For some reason it isn't liking a certain shapefile.  I'll give it a try though.  Thanks.

Comment: I've found more issues trying to build the OGR2OGR statement than I have with the shapefiles - but one thing that people have responded with is that certain fields that usually come with shared shapefiles - that usually come from an eSRI GeoDatabase - is the need to remove fields such as SHAPE_AREA and SHAPE_LENGTH prior to loading with OGR2OGR... just a heads up!